# JavaScript Getting second <td> cell value when clicked on a button on the same row

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

How can I get email cell value when I click on the button which is located at the last cell of the same row.

[Please check this screenshot for better understanding what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UiNL.png)

So when I click Button 1, I want to get Email1 value or when click Button 2, I want to get N2 cell value.

**My HTML Mockup:**

```
function renderCustomers(tasks) {
customerList.innerHTML += `
    <tr >
        <th >Name</th>
        <th >Email</th>
        <th >Contacts</th>
        <th >Address</th>
        <th >Country</th>
        <th >Action</th>
    </tr>`;    
tasks.forEach((t) => {
  customerList.innerHTML += `
    <tr class=" animated bounceInUp">
        <td >${t.Name}</td>
        <td >${t.Email}</td>
        <td >${t.Contacts}</td>
        <td >${t.Address}</td>
        <td >${t.Country}</td>
        <td ><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="getCustomerEmail">
            Get Customer Email
        </button></td>
    </tr>`;
});
```

}

I found this function but it return the clicked cell value not the one I need:

```
  function getElementID(){
    var tbl = document.getElementById("Results");
  if (tbl != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
              tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () { getval(this); };
      }
  }
  function getval(cel) {
      alert(cel.innerHTML);
  }
  }
```

Any help is really appreciated

I found this function but it return the clicked cell value not the one I need:

```
function getElementID(){
   var tbl = document.getElementById("MyTable");
   if (tbl != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
         for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
             tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () { getval(this); };
          }
      }
    function getval(cel) {
        alert(cel.innerHTML);
      }
      }
```

Comment: Can you add here the HTML markup that creates the table you have on the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply bind a `class` to your `td` and then reference it based on the context of the clicked `button`.

```js
function getEmail(el) {
  const tr = el.closest('tr');
  const tds = tr.getElementsByClassName('email');
  console.log(tds[0].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Salvino</td>
    <td class="email">salvino@example.com</td>
    <td><button onclick="getEmail(this)">Button</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Someone</td>
    <td class="email">someone@example.com</td>
    <td><button onclick="getEmail(this)">Button</button></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: up vote, but el.closest("tr") would be better than using parentElement.parentElement

Comment: really thnx, its working perfectly